# GridLayout and GridData in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

What the relation between the two? Why do you have to provide both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Layouts are there to give your windows a specific look. A layout controls the position and size of children in a Composite. `org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout` is just an specific instance of `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Layout`, which allows you to layout the child components of a composite in a Grid (row-column) manner.

Each widget controlled by a `org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout` can have its initial width and height specified by setting its `org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData` object.

So, the `org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout` is basically a blue print which describes the layout of controls on a composite.

Whereas the `org.eclipse.swt.layout.Griddata` is the attribute of the control, describing its span, indentation, margin etc for each gird(cell). Each component should have a unique Griddata.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of SWT, `GridLayout` an SWT layout manager (i.e., it controls the layout of the form). `GridData` is a part of GridLayout and enables you to set layout properties on the SWT components participating in the layout. For instance, you can set the horizontal alignment nature of a `List` component by setting a `GridData` via `cmpnt.setLayoutData(gd)`.

Answer (score 1):

GridLayout is the Layout Manager for the controls.

GridData specifies how the controls in each cell of the layout behave while displaying.

Answer (score 0):

GridLayout is one of standard layout managers introduced in java 1.0 15 years ago and belongs to package java.awt.
GridData is a SWT extension.